# Passing a mathematical function as a parameter

Tags: python, math

How can you can put a mathematical function in a parameter of a Python function?

Something like:

```
def myFunction(function):
      rep = []
      for i in range(100):
            rep.append(function) 
      return rep
```

where `i` would be `x` for example `myFunction(2x-1)`

Comment: I suspect the closest thing to what you want would be a lambda expression, e.g. `lambda x: 2 * x - 1` or just another function that does that. Not sure if there's any "native" math interpreter the way you want it

Comment: What's up with the capitalization? Except for `Rep`, those are all syntax errors.

Comment: @Mena There is third-party library sympy

Answer (score 2):

Using a lambda function should work which Python treats as an anonymous function. Here is the code:

```
def myFunction(math_function):
    rep = [] 
    for i in range(100):
        rep.append(math_function(i))  
    return rep

result = myFunction(lambda x: 2*x - 1)
print(result)
```

However, if the function is very complex, you may prefer defining it with another def statement instead, such as:

```
def myMathFunction(x):
    return 2*x - 1  # Replace this with any mathematical operation you need

result = myFunction(myMathFunction)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could pass a `lambda` to a function like that:

```
def myFunction(function):
      Rep = []
      for i in range(100):
            Rep.append(function) 
      return Rep

functions = myFunction(lambda x:2*x-1)
```

Comment: I think they want `Rep.append(function(i)) `